# Select the particular list from IList

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am using ImageListView dll in windows application, one of my situation I need to select the last index value from IList.

My existing working code

```
var items = ((flag == 1) ? (IList<ImageListViewItem>)imageListView1.Items : (IList<ImageListViewItem>)imageListView1.SelectedItems);

foreach (ImageListViewItem item in items)
{
  ...
}
```

I am trying to select the first value from IList using below code

```
var items = ((flag == 1) ? (IList<ImageListViewItem>)imageListView1.Items : (IList<ImageListViewItem>)imageListView1.SelectedItems[0]);

foreach (ImageListViewItem item in items)
{
  ...
}
```

If i trying by the above code I got the following error
"**Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Manina.Windows.Forms.ImageListViewItem' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1**"

Comment: Try changing `var items = ((flag == 1) ? (IList<ImageListViewItem>)imageListView1.Items : (IList<ImageListViewItem>)  imageListView1.SelectedItems[0]);`
 to `var items = ((flag == 1) ? (IList<ImageListViewItem>)imageListView1.Items : (IList<ImageListViewItem>) new[] { imageListView1.SelectedItems[0]});`

Comment: looking at your error it looks like a cast exception. I am unsure what you are trying to do but I'd say the mistake is in your casting. I.e. `(IList<ImageListViewItem>)imageListView1.SelectedItems`

Comment: What's the goal here?  You are trying to select a single item, but you're also expecting a list you can iterate through.  Which is it?  Do you want a single item (in which case, what do you want when `flag == 1`?), or do you want a list with the first selected item in?

Comment: @Adiaan Stander Great it is working fine, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to cast a single `ImageListViewItem` to an `IList<ImageListViewItem>`.  You need to create a new list containing this item if you want to stick to that contract.

I think the ternary operator and lots of casting is hurting the readability a lot here, so how about a helper method:

```
private IList<ImageListViewItem> GetItems(int flag)
{
    IList<ImageListViewItem> items;

    if (flag == 1)
    {
        items = imageListView1.Items
    }
    else
    {
        items = imageListView1.SelectedItems.Take(1).ToList();
    }

    return items;
}
```

This will also ensure returning an empty list when there are no items currently selected rather than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
foreach (ImageListViewItem item in imageListView1.SelectedItems)
{
   //Use you item here.
  ...  
  //In case flag is raised - break the loop after firs item use.
  if(flag == 1)
    break;
}
```